# Find lists in list of lists with the most instances from another list

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
a = [10,9,1,2,3,4]
```

And a list of lists:

```
b = [[1,2,3],[6,9,10],[4,5,7,8]]
```

I want to get:

```
c = [[1,2,3],[6,9,10]]
```

Where `c` is the list of top 2 lists in `b` with the most instances in `a`.
These can be large, so performance could be an issue.

Not sure if this makes a differences, but each element is present only once in a and the entirety of b and is an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The heapq module has a `nlargest` function that will efficiently get you the top `n` values from a list without sorting the whole thing.  Use a set to get the intersection of values in `a` with each sub list:

```
from heapq import nlargest


a = [10,9,1,2,3,4] 


b = [[1,2,3],[6,9,10],[4,5,7,8]]

aSet = set(a)
c    = nlargest(2,b,key=lambda n:len(aSet.intersection(n)))

print(c)

[[1, 2, 3], [6, 9, 10]]
```